# How can I make pill buttons look like links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I style buttons to make them look and behave exactly like links in Bootstrap Vertical Pills? `btn-link` does not do this (hover over each in the snippet).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Button</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the styling that is added, the `.btn` elements are `inline-block`, while the `a` elements that are descendants of `li` elements are `block` level.

Therefore you could simply give the `.btn-link` element a width of 100%, and change the `display` to `block` and add the corresponding `padding`/`border-radius`:

```css
.nav-pills>li>.btn.btn-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
.nav-pills>li>.btn.btn-link:hover,
.nav-pills>li>.btn.btn-link:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Button</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The main downside I've found to this is it appears to break responsive design. When the page is viewed in a smaller window, these buttons behave differently from regular pills. This could be specific to our styling/scripting; I'm still investigating.

Comment: @TrueWill I can take a look if you provide me with an example.

Comment: Thanks - I think we figured it out.